# Disable past date, Sundays and after 11am (goes to next day) jQuery datepicker in Gravity Form

Tags: jquery, datepicker, uidatepicker, gravity-forms-plugin

Ok, so I'm trying to edit the datepicker in my Gravity Form. It's a simple order for for flowers but I'm wanting to make it so you can't pick past dates, Sundays (we're closed) and if it's after 11am CST then it would block that day and go to the next.

Currently I've found a way to block past dates but anything and everything I've tried to disable Sundays has not worked, and I have no idea how to disable the day after 11am.

If anyone could lend a hand, that would be great! Thanks!!

What I have so far for the blocking of the past dates:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#input_1_5").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $(function () {
     $("#input_1_5").datepicker({
        minDate: new Date().getHours() >= 11 ? 1 : 0,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day !=0 ), ''];
        }
     });
   });
```

Comment: And where can you select hours in datepicker?? there is no difference at all between my answer and this one, since you are disabling Sundays, so the Sunday Hours is not gonna be used at all.